# Fundamental Group of Circle Generator Textbook Typo?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm confused about what the generator is for the fundamental group of a circle at point $b_0$.  That is, what is the generator for $\pi_1(S^1, b_0)$.  Is it $e^{2\pi i (t_0 + t)}$ for $t \in [0, 1]$, where $b_0 = e^{2\pi i t_0}$?  My book says it is $e^{2\pi i t}$ for $t \in [0, 1]$, but this seems to have no dependence on $b_0$.  Just want to see if this is a typo.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Through the use of the covering map $f(x)=(\cos (2\pi x,\sin 2\pi x))$, you get that the fundamental group of a circle is isomorphic to the integers under addition.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo to me (or maybe the book said that $b_0 = (1, 0)$ earlier...)

Comment: Would what I said be the generator for a more general $b_0$?

Comment: Absolutely -- I forgot to confirm that. You've done a nice close reading of the text -- good work!

Answer (score 0):

Since $S^1$ is path-connected, the fundamental group is independent of the choice of point, and will be the same at any base point.

Comment: I'm talking about the generator of the group though.  This should depend on the base point.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you're right.